# INSERT to Oracle intermittent latency c#

Tags: c#, oracle

I have a **C#** app that basically generates massive amounts of data for a test database. It is using **Oracle.DataAccess** Version **4.112.3.0**

For some strange reason about every 30ish inserts the OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() statement will hand for **several** seconds. We are talking in some cases ***15 seconds!***

I did not have this problem when using a generic ODBC connection via a DSN....
I cannot go back to using a DSN as I want this application to work even on systems that do not have an oracle client installed.

Any help is **greatly** appreciated

**Code for my connection class, handles opening the connection and doing the insert - setup to work for both SQLServer and Oracle**

```
public Connection(string username,
            string password,
            string serverAddress,
            String servicename,
            string qual)
        {
            uid = username;
            pwd = password;
            server = serverAddress;
            oraServiceName = servicename;
            qualifier = qual;
            string oradb = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION="
                             + "(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=" + serverAddress + ")(PORT=1521))"
                             + "(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME="+servicename+")));"
                             + "User Id=" + username + ";Password=" + password + ";";
                oraConn = new OracleConnection(oradb);
                oraCom = new OracleCommand("",oraConn);
                oraCom.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;


        } 
public void doInsert(string s)
        {

            try
            {
                sqlCom.CommandText = s;
                sqlCom.Connection = sqlConn;
                sqlCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException e)
            {
                try
                {
                    oraCom.CommandText = s;
                   // oraCom.Connection = oraConn;

                    oraCom.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }
                catch (NullReferenceException e2)
                {
                    throw e2;
                }
            }

        }
```

**CODE THAT ACTUALLY DOES THE INSERTS**

```
public void generateData()
    {
        try
        {
            indivID = GenerateId();
            conn.openConn();
            conn.doInsert(tData.insertIndividual());
            //number of calls
            for (long x = 0; x < numCalls; x++)
            {
                countCalls++;
                callidkey = GenerateId();

                //start segments
                for (long y = 0; y < numSegments; y++)
                {
                    if (countSegs != numSegments)
                    {
                        countSegs++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        countSegs = 0;
                    }
                    INTX_ID = GenerateId();
                    conn.doInsert(this.tData.insertINTXSEGMENT());
                    //start parts and recordings
                    for (long n = 0; n < numParts; n++)
                    {

                       // INTX_PART_ID = GenerateId();
                        conn.doInsert(tData.insertINTXPART());
                        if (countParts != numParts)
                        {
                            countParts++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            countParts = 0;
                        }
                        if (genRec)
                        {

                            recData.recordingid = GenerateId();
                            conn.doInsert(recData.insertRecData());
                            conn.doInsert(recData.insertRecPart());
                            if (countRecs != numParts)
                            {
                                countRecs++;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                countRecs = 0;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {}
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a programmer, just a dba.
There are a few things to remember:

1. re-use open connections when possible - connection management takes ages.
2. use bind variables for your inserts, preferably with bulk collect.

If you implemented those 2 simple rules, next thing to check is the database online redolog file size. Default they are 512KB. If they are full, your app will freeze until there is room in the next redo file. redo's are used in a round robin fashion. When they are filled they are copied to an archive, if the database is in archivelog mode. This might cause a slowdown while doing many inserts.

check logmode of the database:

```
select log_mode from v$database;
```

check redo size and count of groups:

```
select group#, bytes, first_time from v$log;
```

The redo's should be on very fast storage. It is only doing sequential io.
If the redo's are small compared to the normal load, increase their size. (normally we aim to have about a log switch every 15 minutes) If you constantly have more, increase the size.
If normally you have about 4 switches in an hour and only your load fills them very quick, add log groups.

Comment: Thanks for the info I will check they and update you.can you think of any reason why a dsn based connection wouldn't do this? Also I am reusing the same connection. Connection is a class that open the connection and then I feed a string to connection.doinsert that will handle the insert.

Comment: I don't know what dsn based does different than what you do. I do not recognize any variable bind actions.

Comment: Ok I checked and the Logmode is NOARCHIVELOG - I did change the code to do explicit commits, this helped a little - I did find a couple of instances with 60+second inserts most I've had since doing the explicit commits is 20 seconds. Which is still waaaaay to long so any input is appreciated.

Comment: what is the size of the redo's ? Do you have constraints and/or triggers and/or indexes on the tables?

Comment: There were 3 logs for the last 24 hrs. each was 50meg. The tables are all related.  
Table) INTXSegment  
Table) INTX_Particpant  
Table) RECINTXPARTICIPANT  
Table) RECORDINGDATA  

INTXSegment has a PKey char(22) (guid)

INTX_Particpant has a PKey char(22) (guid) and FKey pointing to INTXSegment

RecordingData has PKey char(22) (guid)  

RECINTXPARTICIPANT has PKey char(22) (guid) and 2 FKeys one to INTX_Participant char(22)
and one to RecordingData char(22)

You were talking about Bind variables - are you saying that so Oracle does not have to do a <<Hardparse>> ?

Comment: yes, prevent hard parsing as much as you can. Also: committing should make it all even slower.... 50MB logs are not the silly defaults ... What is the db version? I think it is time to look for wait events.

Comment: This is 10g 10.2.0.4
I did turn on tracing for my session though I looked at the trace files and they make no sense to me whatsoever.

Comment: do you have lines that stat with WAIT ? if not, redo with wait events enabled for the trace. use ALTER SESSION SET events '10046 trace name context forever, level 12'; or EXECUTE SYS.DBMS_SYSTEM.SET_EV (sid, serial#, 10046, 12, ''); The WAIT events will/should give a clue.

Comment: call     count       cpu    elapsed       disk      query    current        rows
Parse        1      0.00       0.00          0          0          0           0
Execute      1      2.37    1032.94      66491      66215      79714           1
Fetch        0      0.00       0.00          0          0          0           0

total        2      2.37    1032.94      66491      66215      79714           1

Misses in library cache during parse: 1
Optimizer mode: ALL_ROWS
Parsing user id: 85

Comment: A bit unreadable. Can you grep on ^WAIT in the trace file? Also, are this simple inserts? End the trace with a clean exit from oracle.

Comment: I've re-written this to use SPROCS - now I'm having a problem with a FKEY constraint ... its a problem because I am satisfying it and it fails when ran in code. But succeeds when ran manually.... *sigh* I knew I liked SQLServer for a reason.